# Enumerations in OWL Restrictions

Tags: ontology, owl, protege, manchester-syntax

I am trying to add restrictions to properties in an ontology using Protege3.x.

I have a problem specifying enumerations inside restrictions. For example trying to specify a enum to restrict the possible data elements in this way:

[image]

which considers the whole expression as a single string:

[image]

In another example, I tried solving the problem by using multiple expressions and 'or' between them, which seems to be appropriate. But in the previous one, no 'or' is allowed.

[image]

How is it possible to use enumerations for this need? Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to do OWL modeling, Protege 4 is a far better option than Protege 3, imo.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, I've found this issue is easily solved in protege 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is solved using Protege 4.

The following expression was used in the class Superclasses attribute:

```
hasRole only {"physician_generalPractice", "specialist_neurologist", "specialist_neurosurgeon"}
```